# Unable to create a working sprite

Tags: lua, sprite, coronasdk

I am unable to create a working animation sprite for this single area of my app.

I am using Corona SDK and have the following sprite:

[image]

This is names `mainCharacter.png`. I have a double sized version called `mainCharacter@2x.png`.

I have sheet options, 2 sequences, I'm building an image sheet and passing that to my sprite:

```
local playerSheetOptions =
{
    width = 50,
    height = 50,
    numFrames = 17,
    sheetContentWidth = 500,
    sheetContentHeight = 100
}
local playerSequences = {
    {
        name = "idle",
        start = 1,
        count = 12,
        time = 1200,
        loopCount = 0,
        loopDirection = "bounce"
    },
    {
        name = "jump",
        start = 13,
        count = 5,
        time = 600,
        loopCount = 1
    },
}
local playerSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "resource/images/mainCharacter.png", playerSheetOptions )
local player = display.newSprite(gameSheet, playerSheet, playerSequences)
```

I am getting the following error:

`display.newSprite() requires argument #2 to a table containing sequence data`

If I `print` the relevant data:

```
print(gameSheet)
print(playerSheet)
print(playerSequences)
```

I get:

```
14:27:05.703  userdata: 12445228
14:27:05.703  userdata: 0CF42600
14:27:05.703  table: 0CF41FD0
```

Where am I going wrong?  I have tried simplifying the sequences a lot, but still get the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
local player = display.newSprite(playerSheet, playerSequences)
```

instead of

```
local player = display.newSprite(gameSheet, playerSheet, playerSequences)
```

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/spriteAnimation/index.html#sprite-objects)

> Once the image sheet(s) and sequences are set up, a new sprite object
> can be created with the display.newSprite() API:
>
> display.newSprite( [parent,] imageSheet, sequenceData )
>
> For this API, the parent
> parameter is optional and represents the display group in which to
> insert the sprite. The imageSheet parameter defines the default image
> sheet for the sprite, and sequenceData is the table that contains all
> of the sequences for the sprite.

Read more about [Sprite Animation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/spriteAnimation/index.html#sprite-animation).

Comment: But I need to insert it into `gameSheet`.  It's complaining that `imageSheet` isn't correct

Comment: The first argument for `newSprite` should be group name but `gameSheet` variable  doesn't imply it is `display group`. So I remove it. I tested your code. It works on my computer.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I had the wrong variable name there.  Thanks :)